# Android - Start Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

When searching for how to launch Intents some people have listed like below.

Can you launch an Intent with the following lines? How would you do it?

Display Settings

```
#Intent;component=com.android.settings/.DisplaySettings;end
```

Sound Settings

```
#Intent;component=com.android.settings/.SoundSettings;end
```

Wireless Settings

```
#Intent;component=com.android.settings/.WirelessSettings;end
```

Dialer

```
#Intent;component=com.android.contacts/.DialtactsActivity;end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first line, it will be

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DisplaySettings");
startActivity(i);
```

The rest of them will be similar to this.

Comment: As well as doing it like what Wenhui has said you can also do it like: `try {startActivity(Intent.getIntent("#Intent;component=com.android.settings/.DisplaySettings;end"));
               } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
               }`