# Starting an intent programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How can I start an intent programmatically? I've written code that starts intent by click on certain button, but how can I run same intent in this case: 
Let's say I have variable j=0, that increments in loop. When j receives value of 10, intent must be started. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Not sure if duplicate, but is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202436/3751577

Comment: your question makes no sense. Both are executed in java

Comment: @Tim Castelijns my question is how can I start intent without click on button.

Comment: @Hexaholic thank you very much, I will try this when I come home.

Comment: why would you think you need a button to use an intent

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. Post some code and indicate what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

```
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if (j==10)
            startActivity(new Intent(current context, target class));
    }
```

n =  whatever number you have in mind for your loop's end, maybe `.size()` of a `List`, or any other number;

current context = the context from which you wish to fire the intent, could be something like `getApplicationContext()`, `getBaseContext()`, `yourCurrentActivity.this`, `getActivity()`(if you're using a fragment), ...;

target class = the class on receiving end of your explicit intent, for example `GalleryActivity.class`, `SecondActivity.class` ,or anyother class you have in mind;

Answer (score 0):

just like you would with an `onClick()` event, simply fire your `startActivity(new Intent())` when loop reaches your desired number.

Answer (score 0):

no different than an onClick, just create the new intent and start your activity or service with it